# How to display custom AttributeEvaluator in the Weka GUI

Tags: weka

I implemented a custom `AttributeEvaluator` and also extended the `ASEvaluation` class, so I can evaluate and select the best attributes with `Ranker`. I read the Weka Wiki to find out how to integrate it into the [Weka GUI](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/writing_classifier/#integration), but the link seems to be broken.

How can I display and use my attribute evaluator, or where can I find the document that explains it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Create a jar file containing newly generated evaluator.
- Add the jar file to weka classpath (`cp` key in RunWeka.ini file located in weka install directory)
- If the newly created evaluator is not in default Weka evaluator package (weka.attributeSelection) add new package to GenericPropertiesCreator.props file (key `weka.attributeSelection.ASEvaluation` and/or `weka.attributeSelection.ASSearch`)

  - You can extract this file from weka.jar (weka/gui) and copy to $WEKA_HOME/props directory (eg in Windows: C:\Users\USERNAME\wekafiles\props)

For details check the WekaManual.pdf located in Weka install directory.